# Cool Horizontal tool in android UI

Tags: android

I was surfing some apps couple of hours ago and I saw something common in all of them. One clear instance for that is when you open YouTube app you see a narrow horizontal tool just above the device's home button which seems to be in charge of controlling what page user want To go I guess.
It has search button, a button which leads to the home page of the app and etc.
Question: Is it just a strip with buttons which is used to switch between activities ( by Intent class)? Or something else?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my bro you should use some library for apply this such as chip navigation

if you interest to learn it recommend you to see this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQtdOSN21lQ&feature=emb_logo and the library https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the bottom app bar?

If so you'll find the details here: https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom

And yes you can use it to switch between activities.

Comment: not Activities, these patterns mostly use Fragments.